# Get HTTPConnectionPool data

Tags: python, urllib

I use a open API get the bellow information using its access key:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='freeipapi.17mon.cn', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /183.11.178.118 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x103780780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
{'status': 0, 'address': 'CN|广东|深圳|None|CHINANET|0|0', 'content': {'address_detail': {'province': '广东省', 'city_code': 340, 'street': '', 'city': '深圳市', 'district': '', 'street_number': ''}, 'address': '广东省深圳市', 'point': {'x': '12693451.44', 'y': '2560682.35'}}}
```

You see, the later data `{'status': 0, 'address': 'CN|广东|深圳|None|CHINANET|0|0', 'content': {'address_detail': {'province': '广东省', 'city_code': 340, 'street': '', 'city': '深圳市', 'district': '', 'street_number': ''}, 'address': '广东省深圳市', 'point': {'x': '12693451.44', 'y': '2560682.35'}}}` is my need.

How can I get it?

The code is bellow:

```
import urllib, urllib.request
import json

ak_url="http://api.map.baidu.com/location/ip"

result = requests.get(ak_url,{"ip":"183.11.178.1","ak":BAIDU_IPADDR_AK})

print(result.json())  # There prints the upper data.
```

Comment: so you see that data after printing `result.json()`? It's not clear to me *where* you see that data (or when)

Comment: Yes, the data is printed `result.json()`

Comment: Well, I've seen something like this before. Have you tried accessing those keys? Like `result.json()["status"]`?

Comment: @Adelin Oh, yes! I can, some days ago, I access the `result.json()["status"]`  I may dim eyesight.

Comment: @Adelin Thank you, Adelin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is actually returned by `result.json()`.

Perhaps you are confused by the extra `HTTPConnectionPool` details.

That could be an indicator that `result.json()` has a custom representation (as in, it implements `__repr__` or `__str__`) and appends that data behind the scenes when printing.

Answer (score 0):

Use requests. Much easier. `pip install requests`

Then:

```
import requests

ak_url="http://api.map.baidu.com/location/ip"
BAIDU_IPADDR_AK = 'test'
result = requests.get(ak_url,{"ip":"183.11.178.1","ak":BAIDU_IPADDR_AK})
print(result.json())
```

I get this result:

```
{'status': 200, 'message': 'APP不存在，AK有误请检查再重试'}
```

Comment: That's what I was inclined to answer, but OP actually uses `requests.get`, even though he's importing `urllib.request`.